# How to show if a linear function through a point passed through a curve twice?

Tags: quadratics, discriminant

Show that any linear function passing through P(0, 3)
will meet the curve $$f(x)=2x^2-x-2$$ twice

I tried using the discriminant but the discriminant becomes $$m^2-2m+41$$ and from there you get two values as m however that means that only the gradients for those values satisfy it right? 
I'm quite confused

Answer (score 1):

Note that the discriminant is always positive because *its* discriminant (when viewed as a function of $m$) is always negative. Therefore the equation $2x^2-x-2=mx+3$ always has two solutions, and the question is solved.

Comment: Sorry would you be able to further explain, how would you show it

Comment: @itsokay Do you know the properties of the discriminant of a quadratic equation? If it is negative, the function has no roots and is always positive/always negative; if positive, it has two distinct roots.

Comment: Yes but how would that translate to "its discriminant" sorry I don't really see the link

Comment: @itsokay I meant the discriminant of $m^2-2m+41$.

Comment: I think the part I'm confused about is why the discriminant would always be positive if its discriminant (m2-2m+41) is negative

Comment: @itsokay The discriminant of the discriminant being negative means that the discriminant can never be zero, regardless of $m$. Because the leading coefficient of the discriminant is positive, it is positive for all $m$; it never crosses the zero line.

Answer (score 0):

The discriminant is:

$D=b^2-4ac$

Note that this value doesn't tell you the roots but rather tells you how many there are.

If $D>0$, then there are 2 roots.

If $D=0$, then there is 1 root.

If $D<0$, then there are no roots.